# Is there an easy way to disable CallManager Express in a Cisco CME Router?

Tags: cisco, voip

I have a small network with about 10 Cisco 7900 phones being run by a Cisco UC520 16user Router ([info here](http://cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/voicesw/ps6788/vcallcon/ps7293/product_data_sheet0900aecd8061fb06.html)). I am looking to move to a Hosted VOIP solution and would like to reuse my 7900 Series phones with the hosted voip provider. How can I go about disabling callmanager express and unity express from within the UC520 router so that It only functions as a data router?

Is this a simple configuration change? Or will I need to replace the router with a standard data router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration issues will be the biggest headaches in this transition.

I recommend that you replace the UC520 with a standard data router, ideally one indicated as OK by the hosted IP provider.  I would also recommend that you only use the existing phones if the hosted VoIP provider specifically indicates that they are OK for the system.

As an aside .. I'll bet you could [sell the UC520](http://shop.ebay.com/?_from=R40&_trksid=p3907.m38.l1311&_nkw=uc520&_sacat=See-All-Categories) and the phones as a unit for enough to buy the router and phones for the new system.

Comment: The UC520 is not actually our external facing router. We are purchasing an ASA5505 to replace our Sonicwall that handles that role. The UC520 just operates as a router for one of our separate office's subnets. Thank you for the information :-)